# ggplot2 adding text on a multiple barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like:

[image]

I would like to obtain a barplot with, for each bin, two bars (up and down) and the text of upIDX above the up's bars and text of `downIDX` above the down's bars like

[image]

On `ggplot2`, I could generate the graph with the two bars for each bin but I wasn't able to add the labels above the bars. Here is the script I wrote:

```
df3<-melt(df3,id='bin')
ggplot(df3,aes(x=factor(df3$bin,levels=df3$bin),y=df3$value,fill=df3$variable))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge')+
  coord_flip()
```

Can someone could help me?

Comment: Use `dput(df3)` and add the result to your post instead of showing a screenshot of your data. (The first one can easily be copied and pasted into an R session to reproduce the data set)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df<- data.table(bin=LETTERS[1:4], up=c(9,8,13,2),down=c(0,5,2,1),upIDX=0,downIDX="n")
df <- melt(df, id=1, measure=list(2:3, 4:5))
df[,variable:=factor(variable, labels=c("up", "down"))]
ggplot(df, aes(bin,value1,fill=variable)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value2), position=position_dodge(.9), vjust=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use qplot():

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df<- data.table(bin=LETTERS[1:4], up=c(9,8,13,2),down=c(0,5,2,1),upIDX=0,downIDX="n")
df <- melt(df, id=1, measure=list(2:3, 4:5))
df[,variable:=factor(variable, labels=c("up", "down"))]

qplot(bin,value1,data = df,fill = df$variable)+geom_col(position="dodge") +  geom_text(aes(label=value2),position=position_dodge(.9), vjust=-0.4)
```

[The chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKBtW.jpg)

Comment: how is this any different than the post below? (besides ``qplot``)